# Is there a Java library to simplify Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering if there's any library that provides an interface for easily sending messages via GCM?

Looking at the architectural overview, it seems you have to do an awful lot of stuff yourself (open TCP connections, construct HTTP requests, construct the JSON payload, implement exponential backoff, handle the various types of errors etc).

Surely there's some sort of base implementation of this stuff that I've missed, yeah?

Comment: Yeah... Sample from android sdk, server side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's described on [the demo page](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) and the source [is here](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take advantage of a commercial service such as [AirBop](http://www.airbop.com) for the server-side responsibilities.